# Is it really permitted for travellers to work while visiting Georgia on a tourist visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, legal, georgia-country, work

Last night at a party with lots of expats and Georgians the topic came up that foreigners don't need any special visa or work permit to work in Georgia while they are visiting the country as tourists.

But can this really be true? Both Georgians and foreigners there said it was but I want to find an authoritative source because the consequences for working illegally can include deportation or being banned from future visits. I wouldn't want to tell people to come and work here on their travels if the advice could get them in trouble.

Comment: This would probably be the best question to ask [CRA](http://www.cra.gov.ge/index.php?sec_id=55&lang_id=ENG) or the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.ge)

Comment: I had hunted around on the MFR site a bit with no luck. I'll try the CRA one too thanks.

Comment: I don't think that sites will yield you anything.  Contacting the agencies might.  One thing that was surprising on MFA site that there was no work visas.  So they are either not issued or not required.

Comment: Yes I noticed that myself.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Georgia’s Reforms Associates website called FactCheck [researched this very topic in 2014](http://factcheck.ge/en/article/any-foreign-citizen-could-work-in-our-country-without-any-restrictions-or-quotas-this-practically-never-happens-in-europe-the-us-or-cis-countries/):

> Conclusion
>
> Our research has established that in Georgia certain professions have
>   nationality restrictions due to national and public interests. In
>   order to bring in a verdict, we must also take international
>   experience into consideration. Both strict and lenient, there are
>   certain restrictions and limitations in Europe, the US and CIS
>   countries for granting a work permit to foreign citizens.
>
> **There are, however, no such limitations in Georgia and any alien can start working in Georgia without any permission** (only a temporary
>   residence permit is necessary after the visa has expired).
>
> Compared to the current situation, the initiated draft bill regulates
>   the immigration policy of the country.
>
> Based upon the above mentioned, we conclude that the statement of Paata
>   Kvizhinadze:  “Any foreign citizen could work in our country without
>   any restrictions or quotas. This practically never happens in Europe,
>   the US or CIS countries,” is TRUE.

Since the old law allowing for 360 days visas has been re-approved in 2015, **it is highly likely that there are no employment restrictions for citizens of visa-on-arrival countries.**

The [2015 Georgian guideline on legal migration](http://www.mfa.gov.ge/BlankSite/media/Files/IMMIGRATION_ENG.pdf) also fails to list any restrictions on people arriving to Georgia on tourist visas.

Moreover, a [government website](https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/HtmlPage/Html/View?id=956&lang=Eng) which says "2018" in the footer asserts (emphasis added by me):

> The visa policy of Georgia became comparatively liberal, allowing
>   citizens of 98 countries(table1) to enter, reside, **work** and study in
>   Georgia without the necessity to obtain either visa or residence
>   permit.

Comment: Brilliant find! Here have a few crumbs of rep ...