# Renting apartaments for less than month in Europe?

Tags: budget, europe, rental

In the European countries which I have visit, renting apartments or room for short term, strongly increases its price.

On the other hand, in many of the South Asian countries, price of all terms longer than week is almost the same as for long-term rent.

I am looking for European locations where renting per week would not make it no more then 50% more expensive then renting per month for the similar duration stay e.g. 4 weeks = 1 month.

Comment: can you define "not very expensive"?

Comment: @Dirty-flow Isn't that what the rest of the question does? Not very expensive = similar as long-term rent.

Comment: So to clarify, you're looking for countries with rent that doesn't differ much regardless of short or long term leases.  OK, but are you looking for websites showing these apartments, or just a list of countries where this happens? Because it probably happens to some extent, even if rare, in every country in some form.

Comment: @Annoyed In New York long term rent could vary from about $1000/month to the sky is the limit.  I am sure that in various countries and various cities in Europe the rent could vary just as widely.  So can we put some upper limit on the amount?  Geographical limits might also help.

Comment: @Karlson To be sure we are talking about a distribution but, the odd exception notwithstanding, it's still meaningful to try to characterize it or to speak of a typical long-term rent for a given location/standard. Question is, everything else being equal, do you know a country in Europe where rentals for a few weeks are not routinely 50% more expensive or more?

Comment: In many European countries rental contract for period shorter than 1 year is not even legal. Anything shorter falls under similar legal requirements as hotels.

Comment: @vartec How many is many? I know rental contracts in the Netherlands are typically for one year (initially) and some other countries have zoning restrictions against vacation rentals but I also know several where the tenant (not the landlord) can get out of the contract pretty quickly (1-3 months, including without paying for a full year if they decide to leave before). So it might be illegal *for a landlord* to offer anything less than an unlimited contract but tenants don't have to commit themselves to stay for a year.

Comment: @Annoyed: First hand I know of that requirement in the Netherlands and Spain. In both cases you can get shorter contract, but it's kind of in gray zone, it won't be official rental contract. As far as I know other European countries have similar laws. In theory they are to protect tenants, in practice they are to protect hotel industry.

Comment: @vartec Well, I just told you that it's not the case in several European countries (to be specific: France, Germany, Ireland) so I don't think anything like that can be said in general. For example, in France, the contract is typically unlimited in time but the notice required before interrupting the contract can't be longer than three months (for the tenant). Short rental agreements are not common and limited by law but there is no way a landlord can force you to pay for one year if you wish to leave before that. This is really tenant-friendly and not at all similar to the Dutch law.

Comment: Ireland is also totally different: Most people have no written rental agreement and pay weekly in cash, notice is extremely short especially for new contracts. There is a mandatory booklet (*rent book*) to record these payments that was introduced relatively recently but as you can see, there are a lot of differences between countries.

Comment: Question practically unanswerable until you concentrate on single country. In Germany, for example, you generally look for appartment in 3-months advance, you must be in place, and you are usually expected to show German employment contract. If you come for short stay, usually only hotel and semi-hotel options (appartments for time) which are much more expensive, come into question.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ That seems to rule out Germany and, consequently, to make the question eminently answerable. If other countries can be ruled out this way (and, based on the comments, it's apparently more-or-less the case for Spain or the Netherlands as well) we should zero in on some locales where that's possible (Ireland maybe?).

Comment: @Annoyed the problem is that any possible answer would be probably adapted to single (in best case 2 or 3) countries and useless for other. So either there will be no way to select correct one or the answer would be too long, including all possibilites.

Comment: @MarkMayo I look for both.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ I am not sure that I follow what you mean by “being adapted to a country”, it seems that the name of the country or countries where that's possible would be a valuable answer in itself. And until now we don't even have a single one, so I am not sure that an exhaustive answer would be too long (it could certainly be but that's not obvious to me).

Comment: Also, questions asking for a limited number of countries with some info on each seem perfectly accepted and tractable: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/which-countries-if-any-offer-on-arrival-work-visas http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2287/where-can-a-middle-aged-couple-move-for-a-couple-of-years-working-holiday-and-tr?lq=1 http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22190/besides-arab-muslim-countries-re-israel-are-there-other-countries-which-dont-r

Comment: @uhbif19 I would recommend rolling back the last edit you made since there is a lot of places in Serbia and Albania, for example, where short term rent will come out about 30% more expensive then long term rent, as found on AirBnB, HomeAway and a couple of other sites.

Comment: @Karlson AirBnB is much more expensive, than average price for flats rent.

Comment: @uhbif19 Are you looking for countries where your condition is met en masse?  Or are you looking for places where your conditions can be met?

Comment: @Karlson And again, I will be happy to know any variant (:

Answer (score 4):

Did you check AirBnb? https://www.airbnb.com you can find plenty of stuff, for very short periods.

Comment: -1 I don't think this addresses the question. In my area, Airbnb offers run-of-the-mill vacation rentals/B&B with prices 50 to 100% higher than a similar year-long rental.

Comment: +1 because in my place, AIRBNB does exactly what the OP is asking for. Weird. Isn't it?

Comment: @IanLudr What's your place? That would be an answer! (Whereas a generic reference to Airbnb still isn't)

Comment: I completly agree with @Annoyed. Usualy AirBnb prices is comparable to the prices of hotels.

Comment: It's practically link-only answer. It should provide much more details, like for what areas they are targeting, how does payment look like etc. Link with short sentence is good, but in comment.

Comment: I usually use AirBNB because it is NOT as high as a hotel.  But definitely higher than a long-term lease.